# How to import FMDB to a swift framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sqlite, frameworks

I want to use FMDB in a swift framework. I follow this tutorial http://programmingthomas.com/blog/2014/7/23/sqlite-in-swift-frameworks but i am getting this error.

**Opening import file for module 'Swift': Not a directory**

I did all the steps exactly as mentioned in the tutorial.

Also i tried to import the files (not create a seperate framework) but it gives me an error saying that cannot import a non modular header file.

Comment: Use Bridging-Header for solve your problem.

Comment: You can also use objective -C FMDB classes and import it to Bridging header  that your problem also solve.

Comment: Bridging-Headers are not supported in frameworks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI, you can now build framework for FMDB using the `master` branch, and using the `swiftFramework` branch that I discussed below is no longer needed. (That branch was created because of a problem in Xcode 6 and 7 that prevented the creation of frameworks that referenced non-modular headers.)

For example, see issue #[540](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/540) for an example of how to build the frameworks using Carthage. Note, you don't have to use Carthage, but it demonstrates that the `swiftFramework` branch isn't needed anymore.

I'll keep the original answer below for historical purposes, but it appears that it is no longer applicable. We can build FMDB framework without incident now in Xcode 8.

---

There is a FMDB branch (see [`swiftFramework` branch](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tree/swiftFramework)) that was created to allow you to create a separate framework for FMDB. For instructions on how to use it, see [Using FMDB in a framework](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tree/swiftFramework#using-fmdb-in-a-framework) discussion at the end of the README for that branch.

Note, this is a separate branch and has not been integrated into the `master` branch (and probably won't until FMDB 3.0 because it includes some trivial, yet non-backward compatible changes). So, if you don't need it in a framework, I'd suggest just adding the the source to your project directly, rather than separate framework. But if you need a framework, the above branch may help you out.

Comment: I followed the instructions but when I try to build I get `invalid argument '-compatibility_version 1' only allowed with '-dynamiclib'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RyanH. - Hmm. I just tried following the instructions there and the creation of the framework worked fine. Obviously, the code sample at step 8 is outdated (that's old Swift 1.2 code), but steps 1-7 which outline how to create the framework worked fine for me. I suspect something else in your project. Try it in a new blank project and see if you can reproduce the problem. Assuming you can, perhaps you can go to Xcode's "Report Navigator", and identify at which step of the process do you see that warning.